# Specified method is not supported nhibernate 3

Tags: c#, nhibernate

i recently migrated from nhibernate 2 to 3, the problem i have is , in most of query i had before i have a problem right now.
and i see this error Specified method is not supported 
although they all work well in hibernate 2 . one on these query is like this

```
 public JsonResult AllEducationDegree(string search)
    {
        var data = Repository<EducationDegree>
          .FindBySpecification(new EducationDegreeSpecification().Search(search))
          .Take(10)
          .Select(p => new NameValue(p.Title, (int)p.Id))
          .ToList();
         // .AsDropdown(" ");
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

public class EducationDegreeSpecification : FluentSpecification<EducationDegree>
{
    public EducationDegreeSpecification Search(string EducationDegreeSearch)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(EducationDegreeSearch))
        {
            string[] searchs = EducationDegreeSearch.Split(' ');
            foreach (string search in searchs)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
                {
                    AddExpression(p => p.Title.Contains(search));
                }
            }
        }
        return this;
    }

}
```

Comment: Which method is not supported?

Comment: @Paco - I suppose that is the question

Comment: @Adrakadabra - I have the same problem. I've isolated it to my use of ".Where(x => ...), but I have no idea what to do instead.

Comment: @JohannesH - Is that cynical or do you also have no idea how to ask a proper question?

Comment: @Paco - Sorry I didn't mean to be rude. What I meant was that I had the same problem and the error message isn't very helpful. In my case hte error turned out to be caused by calling the linq extension methods in the wrong order. It had nothing to do with a particular method.

Comment: @ JohannesH mine is exactly like urs, and i dont have any idea what can i do

Comment: When you know which method is not supported, somebody can tell if it is supported in the current NHibernate version or if it is a known issue. Most of the times, you can find the method in the stacktrace. Otherwise, you can debug and get clues from the expression tree of the predicate passed to the "Where". When you cannot get a clue, the problem might also be in the repository or fluentspecification class. If you edit the question with the method that you find, or how your tried finding it and it stayed unfindable, somebody can probably help you with the answer or how to go on.

Comment: i'm having the same issue, and seriously have no idea what to look at right now ...

Comment: @alexandre: i am totally sure its nhibernate 3's problem, because i havent had it when i was using the previous version, and right now i have to execute two ore more queries instead of one, for resolving such problems

Answer (score 3):

You need to select before Take. It should work.

```
   var data = Repository<EducationDegree>
      .FindBySpecification(new EducationDegreeSpecification().Search(search))
      .Select(p => new NameValue(p.Title, (int)p.Id))
      .Take(10)
      .ToList();
     // .AsDropdown(" ");
    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just have similar problem, and it happen because property, which was mapped as "many-to-one"  have attribute lazy="no-proxy". I removed that, and it works. Problem is probably because this property was used in **where** part of query. Like:

```
 EntityType aliasEntityType = null;
 PropertyType aliasPropertyType = null; 

 QueryOver.Of<EntityType>(() => aliasEntityType)
 .JoinAlias(() => aliasEntityType.Property, () => aliasPropertyType)
 .Where(() => aliasPropertyType.SomeValue == someValue)
 ....
```

So, Property of type PropertyType shouldn't have lazy="no-proxy". I have tried to implicitly fetch Property, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In the last few lines...

```
AddExpression(p => p.Title.Contains(search));
```

if p.Title is null, then you'd get "specific method is not supported." You could try writing

```
AddExpression(p => p.Title != null && p.Title.Contains(search));
```

or using C# 6

```
AddExpression(p => p.Title?.Contains(search));
```